# improvements to this php function to calculate monthly returns from a set of price data

Tags: php, finance

I have made this function that should take a set of price data and calculate a set of monthly returns. The idea is that is should be able to cope with irregular time intervals.
For example I have daily data for the S&P 500 but many hedge funds only release price data monthly.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
//Turns a price series into an array of monthly returns. 
function monthlyReturns($dates, $prices, $startDate = "", $endDate = ""){
if ($endDate == "") $endDate = time();

if (count($dates) != count($prices)){
die("The dates array must be the same length as the prices array");
}  
$i = 0; $firstPass = false;
foreach ($dates as $date){
  $d = strtotime($date);
  if ($startDate == "" || ($d >= $startDate && $d <= $endDate )) :
    $p = $prices[$i];
    $month = date('M',$d);
    $year = date('Y',$d);

    if ($i == 0 || $firstPass == false){
      $startPrice = $p;
      $lastMonth = $month;
    }

    if ($month != $lastMonth && $i != 0){
      $returnTable['date'][] = $dates[$i-1];
      $returnTable['return'][] = $p / $startPrice - 1;
      $startPrice = $p;
    }
    $lastMonth = $month;
    $firstPass = true;
  endif;
  $i++;
  } 
  return $returnTable;
}
```

I noticed that for a fund with only monthly data the returns are off by a month. Can anyone see any major flaws with this function that could explain this or a solution to solve it.

For info, the monthly returns for hedge funds often come near the end of the month. E.g.

```
date       | Price
-----------------
2013-01-29 | 25.69
2013-02-28 | 27.62
2013-03-30 | 26.53
2013-04-29 | 28.45
```

Comment: There i no actual question here. It would probably be better posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is "why are the returns offset by 1-month for monthly price data whilst daily or weekly data seems correct?" I shall however post to codereview.

Comment: Is there something wrong with that monthly price data is offset by 1-month? I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Yes. So using the data in my question the monthly return for 2013-02-28 should be 7.5% (`27.62 / 25.69 - 1`). But this return is being attributed to the next month (2013-03-30) which is plain incorrect